# Karma Angular Unit test how to create unresolved promise and resolve it in single test to check if code in then was only runned after resolution

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have on promise function `waitUntilIsReady`:

```
  (...)

  private inProgressSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)

  waitUntilIsReady(): Promise<void> {
    const untilInProgress = new Subject<void>()

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.inProgress.pipe(takeUntil(untilInProgress)).subscribe((inProgress) => {
        if (inProgress) {
          return
        }

        untilInProgress.next()
        untilInProgress.complete()
        resolve()
      })
    })
  }

  (...)
```

I'm using it to make sure to run some specific code (on init) only when everything is ready.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.waitUntilUserIsReady().then(() => {
      this.otherService.doSomething()
    })
  }
```

First question is: How to write test to check if call to `doSomething()` was only runned after Promise was resolved and not before?

And from above question arise main one: **How to create Promise without resolving it to be resolved after some time in test?**

Something similar to creating `Observable Subject` and calling `next` in test like:

```
const fakeSubject = new Subject<Message>()

describe('Xyz', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<Xyz>
  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: Xyz,
    providers: [
      MockProvider(Service, {
        someObservableToChangeFlag: fakeSubject.asObservable()
      }),
      MockProvider(OtherService, {
        doSomething: jasmine.createSpy()
      }),
    ],
  })

  beforeEach(() => (spectator = createComponent()))

  it('should something', fakeAsync(() => {
    const otherService = spectator.inject(OtherService)

    expect(otherService.doSomething).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

    someObservableToChangeFlag.next()
    tick()

    expect(otherService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }))
```

---

I know only how to test if it was runned, without checking if was in Promise function:

```
escribe('Xyz', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<Xyz>
  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: Xyz,
    providers: [
      MockProvider(Service, {
        waitUntilIsReady: jasmine.createSpy().and.resolveTo(),
      }),
      MockProvider(OtherService, {
        doSomething: jasmine.createSpy()
      }),
    ],
  })

  beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => (spectator = createComponent())))

  it('should "Do something" on promise', () => { // <- This test is not preventing from simply moving logic out side of Promise
    const otherService = spectator.inject(OtherService)

    expect(otherService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('should "Do something" on promise', fakeAsync(() => { // <- Something "like" what I want
    const otherService = spectator.inject(OtherService)

    // Assert if nothing happened
    expect(otherService.doSomething).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    
    // Trigger Promise
    ? promise.trigger() ?
    tick()

    // Assert if logic inside of Promise was called
    expect(otherService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }))
```

I tried

```
waitUntilIsReady: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(Observable.of().pipe(delay(500)).toPromise()),
```

BUT `toPromise` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `beforeEach` function, you could create a `Promise` and assign its `resolve` function to a variable that can be invoked/triggered in the unit test.

```
describe('Xyz', () => {
  let promise;
  let resolve;  
  let spectator: Spectator<Xyz>;
  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: Xyz,
    providers: [
      MockProvider(Service, {
        waitUntilIsReady: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(promise),
      }),
      MockProvider(OtherService, {
        doSomething: jasmine.createSpy()
      }),
    ],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    promise = new Promise((res) => resolve = res);
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should "Do something" on promise', fakeAsync(() => { 
    // given
    const otherService = spectator.inject(OtherService);
    expect(otherService.doSomething).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    
    // when
    resolve();
    tick();

    // then
    expect(otherService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
  
});
```

Comment: I know how to instantly resolve or reject Promise I posted it in my question (6 block of code line 7)... 
My question is how to create promise without resolving it and after some time resolving/rejecting it if it's even possible.

Comment: After reading your question carefully again, I changed my answer.